# Modern team site template

Tags: sharepoint-online

I did little bit investigation but can;t find any answer. I need to create a modern team sites template. But for that template which functions can I use?

Answer (score 1):

The “Save site as template” option in the site settings page is removed from the SharePoint Online. To save the site as a template, we can directly access to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/**_layouts/savetmpl.aspx**.

But by default, we cannot save the modern team site as a site template. The “the ‘Save site as template’ action is not supported on this site” error will display when access to **_layouts/savetmpl.aspx**. It occurs because **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** property value of the modern team site is false. We need to set **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** to true to enable this action.

We can change SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled using SharePoint Designer or [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362.aspx).

Here are the steps to change the site properties using SharePoint Designer:

1. Open the site using SharePoint Designer.
2. Click **Site Options** on the ribbon.
   [image]
3. Find the **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** property and change its value to true.
4. Save the changes and then you can visit **_layouts/savetmpl.aspx** to save this site as a site template.

Comment: Careful i dont think this is supported by microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

Within SharePoint Online, they have recently introduced the site template concept called **Modern Site Designs**. With Modern Site Designs, you essentially have the ability to use them in two ways:

1. When creating [New Sites](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-site-templates-modern)
2. Applying a template to [Existing Sites](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/view-and-apply-site-design-template)

Both of these ways are great resources for enforcing governance across your sites and for reducing the amount of time needed for the initial setup.