# SP Online : Save subsite as a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, template

Is there a way how to save team subsite as a template? Because theres no "save site as template" action available.

And will I be able to add the new template as a third option there?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might be possible to save a modern (sub) site as a template using classic features, is not supported. See this thread: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Save-Modern-Team-Site-as-a-template-amp-provision-using-Classic/td-p/95307

If you want to use a site as a template, check out the PnP Provisioning Powershell cmdlets. Here's a good blog post describing the process for a classic publishing site. http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/10/29/save-publishing-site-as-template-the-right-way-using-pnp-provisioning/

Comment: As stated by Martijn this is not supported check this Answer for possible workaround (still not supported) https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227790/modern-team-site-template

Answer (score 1):

Saving site as a template is not supported on "modern" team site. Also not supported for sub sites in site collections which root site is a group associated team site or communication site.

Refer to the section what's not supported on "modern" team sites:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

Answer (score 1):

Within SharePoint Online, they have recently introduced the site template concept called **Modern Site Designs**. With Modern Site Designs, you essentially have the ability to use them in two ways:

1. When creating [New Sites](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-site-templates-modern)
2. Applying a template to [Existing Sites](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/view-and-apply-site-design-template)

Both of these ways are great resources for enforcing governance across your sites and for reducing the amount of time needed for the initial setup.